# Add Basic HTTP Auth on the entire site hosted on Nginx

Tags: magento2, nginx

During development, I would like to block access to the entire site. I created a `.htpasswd` file and I can't work out where to add the following two lines:

```
auth_basic "Restricted Content";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
```

Any tip is much appreciated!